# Can we stop and resume a private blockchain while keeping the recorded data intact?

Tags: go-ethereum, private-blockchain

I use the following two lines to initiate and run a private blockchain. Assume I have sent some transactions to it and now for some reasons (e.g. server is malfunctioning) I need to restart the chain. My chain is run on only one node/server (so there is no network and everything is running on one server)

```
   geth --identity "MyNodeName" --rpc --rpcport "8545" --rpccorsdomain 
   "*" --datadir Users/TestChain1 --port "30303" --rpcaddr "127.0.0.1"  
   --nodiscover --rpcapi "db,eth,net,web3,personal" --networkid 123 
   init /Users/CustomGenesis.json


 geth --identity "MyNodeName" --rpc --rpcport "8545" --rpccorsdomain 
 "*"  --datadir Users/TestChain1 --port "30303" --nodiscover --rpcapi 
 "db,eth,net,web3,personal" --networkid 123 console
```

**Question**: Can I stop the blockchain and then re-run the blockchain without losing any data stored in it?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

Just skip the first command (so no init) and geth will take the chaindata saved at Users/TestChain1 to continue :)